# Did Brother Yun escape a maximum security prison without help?

Tags: china, miracle, prisoner

Liu Zhenying (known as [Brother Yun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brother_Yun)) is an exiled Chinese Christian evangelist.

Supposedly, he was sentenced to a maximum security prison some time ago and escaped miraculously, and "without any human help" - according, supposedly, to an investigation by the Chinese government.

However, the only references I can find supporting this claim are from his autobiography [*The Heavenly Man*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0092GA4AO) and various Christian sites. The [current Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Brother_Yun&oldid=868561681) cites the stories from the book unskeptically.

Is there any independent source which confirms this?

Comment: Not sure about the attribution to / tag of "miracle". This would make any answer in the affirmative, "he did escape without help", basically a concession to spiritual belief.

Comment: Generally speaking, there are very few "independent sources" that get to examine Chinese prisons...

Comment: @MichaelK By independent I meant anybody not invested in Brother Yun. An actual confirmation from the Chinese government itself  past or present would be enough right?

Comment: @83457 The Chinese authorities are — obviously — invested in the issue of the escape since all kinds of inside help — i.e. "corrupt" (by their standards) officials — would be an immense embarrassment that makes a mockery of their supposed "maximum security" prison.

Comment: @MichaelK Right ok. So little chance of light being shed on this?

Comment: @83457 Until China has their own Glasnost / Perestroika-style reforms: very little chance indeed..

Comment: It is telling that I can't find any references to the maximum security prison he escaped from outside of references to the book itself.

Comment: On zh.wikipedia there is a general doubt about the veracity of the entire book but I couldn't find a detailed debunking

Comment: In *The Heavenly Man*, the term "Zhengzhou Number One Maximum Security Prison" is used, but I don't think that is intended to indicate the official name of the prison. If you search for 郑州监狱 (Zhengzhou prison) then you can find pages such as [this one](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/172812749) which confirm the existence of a prison in Zhengzhou. Of course it isn't completely clear that this is precisely the prison that Brother Yun was referring to.

Comment: While I agree that we cannot expect independent confirmation of all aspects of Brother Yun's story, I can at least imagine that the Chinese authorities might confirm that he was locked up in Zhengzhou for a short period of time and then "released." This would corroborate some aspects of Brother Yun's story, though of course not the "miraculous" aspects.